# numpy arrays to Pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have two arrays of wavelength and fluxes.

```
print(wave)
array([3872.06965186, 3872.07965186, 3872.08965186, ..., 6942.82937577,
       6942.83937577, 6942.84937577])

print(flux)
array([0.00278573, 0.00270251, 0.00324619, ..., 0.0014955 , 0.0015335 ,
       0.00155908], dtype=float32)

df1  = pandas.DataFrame({'wave':[wave]})
df2  = pandas.DataFrame({'flux':[flux]})
df = pandas.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
df
                                             wave                             flux
0   [3872.0696518611626, 3872.079651860265, 3872.0...   [0.0027857346, 0.0027025137, 0.0032461907, 0.0...
```

however the output I want is

```
                wave    flux
0    3872.0696518611626 0.0027857346 
     3872.079651860265  0.0027025137 
     3872.0...          0.0032461907
```

Comment: Your solution would work if you did not wrap `wave` and `flux` in lists when creating `df1` and `df2`.

Answer (score 0):

You were passing list of list to the column of dataframe `[wave]` and `[flux]`. When you pass list of list, you intended to pass a list to each row.

Try passing `wave` and `flux` instead.

```
    df1  = pd.DataFrame({'wave':wave})
    df2  = pd.DataFrame({'flux':flux})
    df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)

    print(df)

            wave    flux
    0   3872.069652 0.002786
    1   3872.079652 0.002703
    2   3872.089652 0.003246
    3   6942.829376 0.001495
    4   6942.839376 0.001534
    5   6942.849376 0.001559
```

Here is the most optimal solution if `flux` and `wave` is of same size.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'wave':wave, "flux":flux})
```

Answer (score -1):

You just want:

```
pandas.DataFrame(dict(wave=wave, flux=flux))
```

You've basically done:

```
pandas.DataFrame(dict(wave=[wave], flux=[flux]))
```

Note, when you pass a `dict` into a dataframe constructor, it treats it as a mapping of columns. Since your lists have a single item, it is being interpreted as a column with a single row.

Also, `pd.concat` is an unnecessary intermediate step.